# Hapi in memory caching with server methods not accept object as params

Tags: node.js, caching, methods, server, hapi.js

I am currently developing a reverse proxy server using hapi framework on nodejs, have two simple tasks:

1. Sending the api to another server
2. With the response from task 1 do a data merging with some static data

Have no problem with task 1, everything can be cached correctly with pre-settings. But with task 2 it was not that lucky, the error is like below:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
server-0     Error: Invalid method key when invoking: replacer
server-0     at Object.settings.cache.generateFunc.func [as replacer] (/home/jack/WebstormProjects/dcm-reverse-proxy/node_modules/hapi/lib/methods.js:145:51)
server-0     at /home/jack/WebstormProjects/dcm-reverse-proxy/server.js:67:32
server-0     at /home/jack/WebstormProjects/dcm-reverse-proxy/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/catbox/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:850:22
server-0     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
server-0     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

And I finally found the server methods registration can only accept string parameters for generating cache id,

```js
//register
server.method('somemethod', proxyService.replacer, {
    cache:{
        cache: 'inMemCache',
        expiresIn: 5 * 60 * 1000,
        generateTimeout: 2000
    }
});

//calling, argument1 and argument2 must be {string}
server.methods.somemethod(argument1, argument2, function(_error, _result, cached, _report){
...
});
```

If I want to pass `argument1` and `argument2` in different format, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Have found the answer myself, hapi server method has already documented:

> **Generate a custom key**
>
> In addition to the above options, you may also pass a custom function used to generate a key based on the parameters passed to your method. If your method only accepts some combination of string, number, and boolean values hapi will generate a sane key for you. ***However, if your method accepts an object parameter, you should specify a function that will generate a key similar to the following***. Note: Any arguments that are passed to your method are available to the generateKey method, but not the callback.